# How do I run nested queries in sqlx rust?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I want to run a nested query in sqlx. Here's what I've tried:

```
sqlx::query_as!(NseData, "select * from nse_data  where trading_day = (select max(trading_day) from nse_data)").fetch_one(&app_context.db_connection).await?;
```

But it gives me the following error...

```
error[E0658]: attributes on expressions are experimental
  --> db/src/nse_data.rs:30:9
   |
30 |         sqlx::query_as!(NseData, "select * from nse_data  where trading_day = (select max(trading_day) from nse_data)").await?
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #15701 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15701> for more information
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```